# iOS Watch Simulator Crashes Mac

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8, watchkit, watchos-3

I've been fighting with this for a few days now.  Whenever I run a watchKit App from the simulator my mac will get the black screen of death and reboot my machine.  I am running XCode 8.2.1 running simulators for iPhone 6 or 7 and watches with watchOS 3 for both the original watch and version 2 in both sizes.  The watch simulator will start, but whenever it attempts to launch a watchkit app that was deployed with XCode my machine will crash.  This can be any watchkit app, even a simple Hello World app.

I have also tried completely uninstalling XCode 8 and 7 as well as all of the simulators and derived info, but the watch apps will still crash my machine.  I've filed a bug report with Apple, but they won't reply back to me.  I am also running on a Mid 2014 MacBook Pro with Sierra version 10.12.3.

Has anyone else experienced this?  I'm running out of ideas to fix this and I cannot do anything watch related until I get past this.  I've listed some of the logs from the activity monitor below as well as the Panic report:

ACTIVITY LOG:

```
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext unlinking /var/db/uuidtext/FD/2940F9BA8137988BB56CC86EFEDC84
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext unlinking /var/db/uuidtext/FE/872728C5713EA69D9D3FBC6C653C19
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext unlinking /var/db/uuidtext/FE/B838E71BA739F4AA6F121E88E788B5
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext unlinking /var/db/uuidtext/FF/0B49D70BCF30419AD992D76F372F19
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext total: 3188, in_use:2294, marked:0, recent:254, deleted 640
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext slib tree cleaned up (0)
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext uuid tree cleaned up (3)
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: _purge_uuidtext cleaned up (0)
Mar 24 09:04:17 C02N618RG3QD logd[74]: Purged 114692767 bytes from uuidtext.
Mar 24 09:04:18 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe03260b130>: 9223372036854847488.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:18 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe034800ba0>: 9223372036854855680.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:18 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe03260ac80>: 9223372036854855680.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:18 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe0349017f0>: 9223372036854855680.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:18 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe034a07340>: 9223372036854855680.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:18 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe0324107b0>: 9223372036854855680.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:18 C02N618RG3QD useractivityd[1022]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Mar 24 09:04:19 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe034b0e0c0>: 9223372036854855680.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:19 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe0326088d0>: 9223372036854855680.000000]
Mar 24 09:04:19 C02N618RG3QD UserEventAgent[1178]: assertion failed: 16D32 14S471a: com.apple.cts + 20609 [D0046D83-09B7-3C10-A783-396F29B9B380]: 0x0
Mar 24 09:04:21 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.ssm.ScanManager): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:22 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:22 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[30456]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Mar 24 09:04:32 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.ssm.ScanManager): Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:33 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:39 C02N618RG3QD IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[30517]: assertion failed: 16D32: libxpc.dylib + 34617 [D3538D2B-EEA9-3C74-890E-6F4AE4F51F0E]: 0x8d
Mar 24 09:04:40 C02N618RG3QD IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[30517]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
Mar 24 09:04:42 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder WatchKit Tool[30530]: assertion failed: 16D32: libxpc.dylib + 34617 [D3538D2B-EEA9-3C74-890E-6F4AE4F51F0E]: 0x8d
Mar 24 09:04:42 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Mar 24 09:04:42 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder WatchKit Tool[30530]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
Mar 24 09:04:42 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.ssm.ScanManager): Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:43 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30670]: assertion failed: 16D32 14C89: libxpc.dylib + 31485 [0339A402-6531-30E9-8BC2-589C463CD6D6]: 0x8d
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30671]: assertion failed: 16D32 14C89: libxpc.dylib + 31485 [0339A402-6531-30E9-8BC2-589C463CD6D6]: 0x8d
Mar 24 09:04:47 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30670]: assertion failed: 16D32 14C89: libxpc.dylib + 31485 [0339A402-6531-30E9-8BC2-589C463CD6D6]: 0x8d
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30671]: BUG in libdispatch: 16D32 14C89 - 1296 - 0x2
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30670]: BUG in libdispatch: 16D32 14C89 - 1296 - 0x2
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30671]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30670]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30671]: assertion failed: 16D32 14C89: libxpc.dylib + 31485 [0339A402-6531-30E9-8BC2-589C463CD6D6]: 0x8d
Mar 24 09:04:47 C02N618RG3QD Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[30670]: assertion failed: 16D32 14C89: libxpc.dylib + 31485 [0339A402-6531-30E9-8BC2-589C463CD6D6]: 0x8d
Mar 24 09:04:48 C02N618RG3QD IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[30687]: BUG in libdispatch: 16D32 14C89 - 1296 - 0x2
Mar 24 09:04:48 C02N618RG3QD IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[30687]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
Mar 24 09:04:52 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.ssm.ScanManager): Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:53 C02N618RG3QD com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Mar 24 09:04:58 C02N618RG3QD Simulator (Watch)[30853]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Mar 24 09:05:00 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe032706fc0>: 9223372036854857728.000000]
Mar 24 09:05:00 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe0327081f0>: 9223372036854857728.000000]
Mar 24 09:05:00 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe0326114b0>: 9223372036854857728.000000]
Mar 24 09:05:00 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe03250fbf0>: 9223372036854857728.000000]
Mar 24 09:05:00 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe03250d9d0>: 9223372036854857728.000000]
```

AND

```
Mar 24 09:05:53 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe034801f40>: 9223372036854861824.000000]
Mar 24 09:05:53 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: JSON->NS failed [type" : "u",
        "timestamp" : 58798649826108
      },
      "timeGMTsec" : 1490360753,
      "procid" : {
        "procid" : 30972,
        "_type" : "u"
      },
      "persisted" : {
        "_type" : "b",
        "persisted" : 0
      },
      "thread" : {
        "_type" : "u",
        "thread" : 529028
      },
      "pid" : {
        "pid" : 30972,
        "_type" : "u"
      },
      "procpath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneSimulator.platform\/Developer\/SDKs\/iPhoneSimulator.sdk\/System\/Library\/CoreServices\/SpringBoard.app\/SpringBoard",
      "SIMULATOR_UDID" : "4855B6A5-7A82-49AE-94E4-DBA2BED65585"
    }]
Mar 24 09:05:53 C02N618RG3QD diagnosticd[380]: Unexpected xpc type [<double: 0x7fe032403a30>: 9223372036854861824.000000]
```

PANIC REPORT

```
Anonymous UUID:       56E742E7-D1F7-AB9B-90CC-58BFFAFB991E

Fri Mar 24 09:07:31 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8018e05ecd): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8018dfc620, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff806783403c, CR3: 0x00000002cb9b6256, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x00000000ffffff01, RBX: 0x000000002d1e202c, RCX: 0x00000000ffffffa1, RDX: 0x000000000000000a
RSP: 0xffffff921b9fb7c0, RBP: 0xffffff921b9fb7c0, RSI: 0xffffff7f9c364723, RDI: 0xffffff806783403c
R8:  0x0000000000000002, R9:  0x0000000000000ff8, R10: 0xe326417ed3850092, R11: 0xffffff804d3b5bb8
R12: 0x000000000000000a, R13: 0x0000000000000054, R14: 0x0000000000906065, R15: 0xffffff803a652010
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff8018dfc620, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff806783403c, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x4, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff921b9fb450 : 0xffffff8018cf210c 
0xffffff921b9fb4d0 : 0xffffff8018e05ecd 
0xffffff921b9fb6b0 : 0xffffff8018ca3743 
0xffffff921b9fb6d0 : 0xffffff8018dfc620 
0xffffff921b9fb7c0 : 0xffffff7f9c33e471 
0xffffff921b9fb800 : 0xffffff7f9c33e4fa 
0xffffff921b9fb830 : 0xffffff7f9c33e719 
0xffffff921b9fb910 : 0xffffff7f9c33e839 
0xffffff921b9fb950 : 0xffffff7f9c3604fa 
0xffffff921b9fb9a0 : 0xffffff7f9c3603b4 
0xffffff921b9fb9c0 : 0xffffff7f9c3474b7 
0xffffff921b9fbe60 : 0xffffff7f9c3479e1 
0xffffff921b9fbf40 : 0xffffff8202aea6a0 
0xffffff921b9fbf50 : 0xffffff8019227066 
0xffffff921b9fbfb0 : 0xffffff8018ca3c38 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.verdasys.dgagent(23.20.7)[90F4996A-8100-3509-BBCA-9778AAA30E30]@0xffffff7f9c338000->0xffffff7f9c374fff
            dependency: com.apple.security.sandbox(300.0)[8997F7FD-7C04-38F6-86DB-BACDE9137374]@0xffffff7f99937000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: xpcproxy_sim

Mac OS version:
16D32

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.4.0: Thu Dec 22 22:53:21 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.41.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C67A8D03-DEAC-35B8-8F68-06FF7B687215
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018b00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,3 (Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2958365287234
last loaded kext at 359084323236: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   3.1.1 (addr 0xffffff7f998b3000, size 425984)
loaded kexts:
com.McAfee.FMPSysCore   1
com.verdasys.dgagent    0023.20.7
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.1.1
com.squirrels.airparrot.framebuffer 5
com.squirrels.driver.AirParrotSpeakers  1.8
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.14
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.3f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.79
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   278.56
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   278.56
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.GeForce   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.2.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.10
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.3f1
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.57.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.13.79
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.15
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays   380
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  394.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    404.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 404.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   5.0.3f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  252
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    540.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1130.3.1a5
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 278.56
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.1.4
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.1.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   153.3
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.7
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.3f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.3f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.3f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 278.56
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 278.56
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   513.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.79
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.79
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    289.32
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    513.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  307.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.12
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   394.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  131.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540.30.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.3.3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.41.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Verdasys Digital Guardian Agent and McAfee installed, both of which have injected kernel extensions that may be causing the panic.

It appears to be happening during an XPC call's security checks. The Simulator is a separate user space sharing the host Mac kernel. My guess is the developers of one or both kernel extensions are not properly handling certain data or are mangling private kernel data structures. `$rip` is the address of the next instruction. Page faulting on that address means something has gone seriously wrong.

I suggest uninstalling all 3rd-party kernel extensions then attempting to reproduce the problem. If that fixes it then file a bug with Verdasys or McAfee to have them fix their kernel extensions.